# UISwitch Unit test with sendActions(for: .valueChanged)

Tags: swift, unit-testing, uikit, xctest, uiswitch

**GOAL:** I'm currently unit testing the behavior of my UISwitch when it is pressed.

**ISSUE:** My issue I that the `sendActions(for: .valueChanged)` that I use to programmatically change the UISwitch's state is not working as I imagined. It doesn't make it change from `false` to `true` (in my example).

**WHAT DID I DO ?:** I'm using the following path:

1. I declared my UISwitch as `true`
2. I used `sendActions(for: .valueChanged)` for changing it to `false`
3. I finally used `XCTAssertEqual()` to check if it correctly equal to `false` as expected. (I also could have used `XCTAssertFalse()` to check directly if it was `false`.

Ps: I correctly passed `loadViewIfNeeded()` in my `setUPWithError()`

**QUESTION:** How can I test my UISwitch ??

**CODE:** Here is my code:

```
    var sut: ViewController!
    
    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        super.setUp()
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        sut = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController
        sut.loadViewIfNeeded()
    }

    func testGenderButton_ShouldUpdateValueWhenPressed() {
        sut.genderSwitch.isOn = true
        sut.genderSwitch.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
        XCTAssertEqual(sut.genderSwitch.isOn, false, "\(sut.genderSwitch.isOn) should be equal to false")
    }
```

Comment: You seem to have a misconception here. The switch sends the `valueChanged` action when its value changes. Sending the action does not change its value.

Comment: In order to change the UISwitch's value programmatically how would you do it @HangarRash ? By using UI Tests ?

Comment: "In order to change the UISwitch's value programmatically how would you do it" With https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch/1623690-ison

Comment: Thanks @matt, but I meant "change the UISwitch's value programmatically" for testing, by using UI Tests ?

Comment: UI tests don't do anything to the interface "programmatically": they do it by clicking on stuff. What you have is _not_ a UI test, it is a _unit_ test. Anyway, I answered what you asked, which is how to change a UISwitch's value programmatically.

Comment: Also note that your "expectations" are completely wrong in any case. `sut.genderSwitch.isOn = true; sut.genderSwitch.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)` you should expect the value of `isOn` to be _true_ because that is what you set it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't test it. A UISwitch cannot be a subject-under-test!   Unit tests are for logic, not interface, and besides, UISwitch isn't your code — it's Apple's class and you already know how it behaves.

Comment: I'd recommend setting up UI tests for these purposes.
You can test it inside Xcode creating a "UI Testing Bundle" target or using an RPA tool like Appium.

Comment: Ok got it ! But why can we use `.valueChanged` if it is not for `UISwitch` behaviors ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are now asking. I responded to  the question you asked in your Question. If you have a new question, ask it as a new Question.

Comment: Ok @matt ! I'll think about posting a new question, but I need to find some material because that simple by itself will not be encountered by stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

I interpret the question not as literal code to test, but "Why isn't it changing the state?" While we shouldn't test Apple's code, we definitely should unit test our code — including our UI code.

I thought I could pull a trick from my book by pumping the run loop, hoping this would give UIKit a chance to process the event. But this didn't change anything.

Here's what Rachel Brindle writes in [Unit Testing UIKit - Views](https://blog.rachelbrindle.com/2020/06/28/uikit-testing-views/):

```
fooCell.toggle.isOn = false
fooCell.toggle.sendActions(for: .valueChanged) // 5.1
```

> 5.1 This is part of the step of modeling what happens when the user toggles a switch - first I toggle the `isOn` property, then I tell the switch to send the actions for the `valueChanged` `UIControl.Event` - as per the [UISwitch documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch). You’ll note that I do this instead of, say, calling the `onToggle` property of the given cell. This is because the particular mechanism used to notify the view controller/model that the UI changed is an implementation detail and is tested by using the `UISwitch`. In other words, by using `UISwitch.sendActions(for:)`, I’m indirectly asserting the onToggle mechanism, in addition to asserting that the `UISwitch` on the `ToggleTableViewCell` was correctly set up. This also has the additional benefit of making it easier to change how the toggle switch -> update SettingsManager in the future - I don’t need to update the tests and, done right, it’s a green-to-green refactor.

So the correct way to unit test your UISwitch handling is:

1. Set its value to the desired value to test
2. Call `sendActions(for:)` to trigger your code, which responds to the new value.

In other words, this is your chance not to test that Apple changes the value, but to test how your code handles the new value.

Comment: Thanks you @Jon for your well developed and explained answer. It gives me more context to understand the idea behind Unit testing UISwitch 